# How to instance ArrayList<String>[] in Java

Tags: java, arrays, string, generics, arraylist

I am trying to do the following:

```
ArrayList<String>[] names = new ArrayList<>()[];
```

But NetBeans shows Illegal start of expression. Can it be solved without changing to String[][] or `ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>`?

Comment: Maybe you want `ArrayList<String[]>`, i.e. a list of String arrays.

Comment: You can't create an array of parameterized types in Java.

Comment: You can kinda-sorta fake it with something like `ArrayList<String>[] names = new ArrayList[size];`, but you really shouldn't mix arrays and generics.  There's a reason the compiler will give you an unchecked conversion warning if you try that sort of thing.

Comment: An array has a fixed length which must be defined when it is created.  For example, `new int[]` is illegal, but `new int[5]` is legal.